# Importing a csv data table that misses some of its Float type values

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I'm creating a table and want to import (load to postgres) a tab delimited file that has some missing values (empty cells) for some of the columns. I would like these cells to remain empty (or possibly convert them to NULL while performing the loading / or after / or leave them empty just as they are).

I have tried the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE Conclusive_wg_H3K9me3_dn
(
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_sorter float,    
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_geneid character(80) NOT NULL,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_bvi_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_cbk_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_dj_srt float,    
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_evj_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_flv_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_ghw_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_gvz_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_srr_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_AllCount float,  
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_PercentAllCount float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_DynamicCounat float,     
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_PercentDynamic float,    
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_GeneName character(80) NOT NULL,
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_RankSorting float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_NewScore float,
CONSTRAINT Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_geneid PRIMARY KEY (Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_geneid)
);
COPY Conclusive_wg_H3K9me3_dn FROM 'G:\CarrollLab\Teena\ConsolidationWithMethylationData_NoiseBelow32Removed\FromPostgreSQLdb\FigsAndTangentWholeGenes\DynamicWholeGeneValues\OutputFromPostgres\ConclusiveDynamicGenes\Conclusive_wg_H3K9me3_dn.txt' WITH (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL 'NULL',HEADER);
```

If I execute this script using a text delimited file in which all row have all float values, the import procedure works just fine! No troubles.

But, upon attempting to run it using a file with a few empty cells (missing some of the float values) I am running into the following error msg:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY conclusive_wg_h3k9me3_dn, line 9, column conclusive_wg_k9me3_dn_flv_srt: ""
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
SQL state: 22P02
Context: COPY conclusive_wg_h3k9me3_dn, line 9, column conclusive_wg_k9me3_dn_flv_srt: ""
```

Indeed, my 9th line in the txt delimited file has missing data (empty cell) in one of its columns.

Do I HAVE to replace first in EXCEL (for example) all my empty table cells with the string "NULL" ?... 
Would the float type recognize  the NULL string?

Or can I make postgres somehow understand what to do with the empty cells without making a replacement of the empty values by something else?

How can solve this issue? 
Thanks! 
Roy

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved!

I should have change my NULL classification to from 'NULL' to '', accordingly: (see at the bottom too):
WITH (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL '',HEADER);

```
CREATE TABLE Conclusive_wg_H3K9me3_dn
(
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_sorter float,    
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_geneid character(80) NOT NULL,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_bvi_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_cbk_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_dj_srt float,    
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_evj_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_flv_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_ghw_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_gvz_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_srr_srt float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_AllCount float,  
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_PercentAllCount float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_DynamicCounat float,     
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_PercentDynamic float,    
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_GeneName character(80) NOT NULL,
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_RankSorting float,   
Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_NewScore float,
CONSTRAINT Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_geneid PRIMARY KEY (Conclusive_wg_K9me3_DN_geneid)
);
COPY Conclusive_wg_H3K9me3_dn FROM 'G:\CarrollLab\Teena\ConsolidationWithMethylationData_NoiseBelow32Removed\FromPostgreSQLdb\FigsAndTangentWholeGenes\DynamicWholeGeneValues\OutputFromPostgres\ConclusiveDynamicGenes\Conclusive_wg_H3K9me3_dn.txt' WITH (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL '',HEADER);
```